# Can I connect a UDOO to a PC using a straight-through ethernet cable or do I need a cross over?

Tags: embedded-systems

Can I connect a UDOO board to a PC using a straight-through ethernet cable? Or do I need a cross-over cable?

As far as I know, most modern devices can use the two interchangeably. However, I am not sure if a UDOO can do that. Anyone with any experience?

Thank you for your help.

(PS: I don't have a UDOO on me at the moment, so I can't test it myself. Couldn't find any information in the documentation either).

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the [UDOO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDOO) should support [Auto MDI-X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium-dependent_interface#Auto_MDI-X), since the [KSZ9031RNX Gigabit Ethernet Transceiver](http://www.micrel.com/products/lan-solutions/phys/article/2-ksz9031rnx.html) it uses supports it. The only question is whether the driver supports setting MDI auto mode.

Even if it doesn't, only one end of an ethernet link needs to be set up to Auto MDI-X, so if the PC end supports it (most do) then you should be able to set auto mode there and the link work with both straight through and cross over cables.